# При изменении значений в одном ключе словаря, значения меняются и в другом

Tags: python, словари

Ситуация такая: есть словарь с двумя ключами. В этих ключах одинаковые значения. Нужно поменять значения только в одном из ключей, но когда я их меняю они меняются в обоих ключах. Почему так происходит и как этого избежать? Я в питоне новичок и поэтому не могу понять, это как обусловлено самим питоном или я где-то накосячил.

Создание словаря происходит в одном модуле, а правка значений в другом.
к примеру есть такой словарь:

```
self.second_items_list.update({
        'title': title_list,
        'all_price': price_list,
        'one_price': price_list,
    })
```

значения в ключах all_price и one_price одинаковые.
Затем в одном из ключей нужно сделать правку:

```
second_num = self.second_items_list['one_price']
for k, i in enumerate(second_num):
    second_num[k] = round(float(second_num[k]) - 10)
```

так вот вместо того, чтобы править значения только ключа one_price, значения правяться в обоих ключах и в one_price и в all_price

Comment: Напишите пример. Скорее всего дело в ссылках.

Comment: В словарях не может быть двух элементов с одним и тем же ключом: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: Скорее всего в значениях лежит ссылка на один и тот же список. Если я правильно понял вопрос. Приведите работающий пример когда для иллюстрации прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтоб списки работали отдельно , их нужно срезать копией с исходного:

```
'all_price': price_list[:],
'one_price': price_list[:],
```

А простым присваиванием переменная ссылается на исходный список

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @ЕвгенийГончаренко, если вам помог этот ответ, отметьте его как "принятый" (серая галка слева).